# Replace NAT dates with data from another column Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing difficulties replacing NAT dates with data from other column. I am using python pandas by the way.

For example

```
       Column1            Column2
       02-12-2006         2006
       05-12-2005         2005
       NAT                2008
       15-02-2015         2015
       NAT                2001
```

I have the valid dates in column1 and only the years in column2, how can i impute the NAT values using the years from column 2 based on the same row.

My desire result will be

```
       Column1            Column2
       02-12-2006         2006
       05-12-2005         2005
       2008               2008
       15-02-2015         2015
       2001               2001
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
df.Column1.combine_first(df.Column2)

0    2006-02-12 00:00:00
1    2005-05-12 00:00:00
2                   2008
3    2015-02-15 00:00:00
4                   2001
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

---

#### Better Answer

```
df.Column1 = np.where(df.Column1.notnull(),
                      df.Column1.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                      df.Column2)

df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @piRSquared, just one more question, how do i removed the 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

```
df["Column1"] = df["Column1"].fillna(df['Column2'])
```